# Page somehow shows on on left side of screen

Tags: android, css, internet-explorer, mobile, alignment

I have tested a web page on several devices and browsers (PC, tablet, iPad, android mobile phones) and everything looks good.

The only issue I have found is when I test the web page using an Android powered mobile phone, and use IE as the browser.

The web page somehow is pushed to the left side of the screen and the navigation links are not aligned properly. 
This only happens when viewing in Internet Explorer on an android powered phone.

Any idea why this happens and how to fix?

Here is the web page: http://www.nightaccents.com
Here is the CSS:

```
/*CSS RESET*/
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-style: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}


a img { 
    border: none; 
}

a:link {
    color:#666;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:none;
}

a:hover {
    color:#0373ED;
}

a:visited{
    color:#666;
}
#container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.wrapHeader {
    position:relative;
    width:960px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 149px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
    width:297px;
    height: 148px;
}
.nav {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    width: 663px;
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 1;
    text-indent: 135px;
}


#body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:60px;    /* Height of the footer */
}
.wrapContent {
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color: #333;
    padding-top: 10px;
}


#footer p {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
}
.wrapFooter {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #CCC;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10px;
}
</style>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    #container {
        height:100%;
    }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You do have some HTML (style tags and IE comments) in your CSS file. That's probably not what's causing the problem, but I think it would be worth trying without them just in case.

Comment: To elaborate on godfrzero's point, Internet Explorer doesn't run on Android. So, what platform are you actually seeing this on?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the test environment you've mentioned I can't give an exact solution, but usually when things are aligned to the left it's because you don't have margin: 0 auto; on something. That has been my experience at least..

It looks like your #container doesn't have that. Body doesn't either.

I'd also change all your

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
```

to

```
margin: 0 auto;
```